# drop down select switches to first value in list in edit mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down select that is set up like below:

```
<%= select_tag :city_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@regions, :cities, :name, :id, :name) %>
```

It works fine, except that when I load the edit view the list loads the first item in the select, not the saved value. Is there parameter I'm missing? On rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` found here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/option_groups_from_collection_for_select
It has a sixth parameter that is the selected value, so just add the last parameter with the value you want and it will work:

```
<%= select_tag :city_id, 
  option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@regions, :cities, :name, :id, :name, "your_city") %>
```

Comment: I saw that, however I want it to be set to the currently selected value. This is edit more. For new, first one on the list is fine.

Comment: When you edit a record, say it `@record`, you will have all of its attributes, like `@record.nome`, `@record.id`, `@record.city_id`, etc. So you just need to put this information inside the options_groups parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `select_tag` use `select`

```
 # f being your form object
 <%= f.select :city, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@regions, :cities, :name, :id, :name) %>
```

Considering you have a valid association with **city**

Comment: yes, saving changes the city_id, just going back to edit mode shows the first item in drop down list

Comment: Anyway I think MurifoX is right. Just put your city_id value as a sixth parameter. i.e. in his answer exchange "your_city" with @record.city.id